# Unable to install Protractor jasmine screenshot reporter command

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am using below data

1. node - v6.11.3
2. npm - 3.10.10
3. protractor - 5.1.2

When i run the command

```
npm install protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter --save-dev
```

it is displaying below error

```
no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\agudla\package.json'
```

Full output

```
C:\Users\agudla>npm install protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter --save-dev
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\agudla\package.json'
C:\Users\agudla
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@4.4.4
+-- protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter@0.4.1
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY tslint@>= 4 < 6

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\agudla\package.json'
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@4.4.4 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@4.4.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN tslint-language-service@0.9.6 requires a peer of tslint@>= 4 < 6 but none was installed.
npm WARN agudla No description
npm WARN agudla No repository field.
npm WARN agudla No README data
npm WARN agudla No license field.
```

Can anyone help me how to solve this error.

Comment: you could use [Cliptor](https://github.com/igniteram/Cliptor.js)- an interactive cli for protractor, it sets up and download these kind of modules for you.

Answer (score 1):

you do not have any package.json file in your directory "C:\Users\agudla" .

 
Navigate in that directory and do a *npm init* which will create a package.json for you and then run *npm install protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter --save-dev*

Refer this for more details: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/creating-node-modules

Comment: I installed the above mentioned command and add the required code in protractor.conf.js still it is displaying "ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444" message